# Custom Menu WPF(XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, menu, styles

We have dev in our service, a link between wpf xaml with powershell scripts.
Actually, we really not have any hard difficults for every simple controls like textbox, richtextbox, button, etc...

But right now, we want trying to make a menu like notepad for example(file, edit, etc...). The objective is to have a menu style like that : [Black Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyQJX.png)

I have read many threads here and in other website about styling but nothing working(many code are used with the C# so it's complicated to modify it).

If I understand right, we need to create a custom style for our menu. For example, here my menu :

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:eo="http://schemas.essentialobjects.com/wpf/"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="350">
    <StackPanel>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Quit" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
                <MenuItem Header="_Copy" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Cut" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Paste" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Where I need to put the custom style and how? (Background black, text white, hover light blue, submenu background black without white border)

Thanks for your helps and sorry if I'm not clear in my request. Difficult to explain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="menuParentStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>


        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Foreground" Color="White"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Background" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a99f3" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid Margin="-1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3D26A0DA" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                        <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Blue"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Yellow"/>-->
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate2" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FFD7D7D7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Blue"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>-->
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>


    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="_File" Style="{StaticResource menuParentStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}"  >
                <MenuItem Header="_New"  />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Quit" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Style="{StaticResource menuParentStyle}"  ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}"  Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}">
                <MenuItem Header="_Copy"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Cut" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Paste" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </StackPanel>
```

I'm sure it can be optimized, but this can give you the way to go.

regards,

Comment: Yes, it's really good ! I need to modify it a little bit the code but this is exactly the way I need.
Thank you !

Comment: And it's possible to split this part into an other xaml file for optimize the reading?
Like that I can have the main xaml and the template in other file. More easier to modify it after if needed.

Comment: yes. this can be set in any resource dictionary. and in you app.xaml you can define a merge dictionary with all the dictionaries you need.

Comment: Great ! I found it and it work :).
In fact, as I told you, i'm not using app.xaml for example. All files with .cs with not be used. Only .xaml files will be read by my script.